# OutOfMemoryException while converting csv to pdf with 2 million records

Tags: apache, csv, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to convert csv to pdf using apache pdfbox and dhorion boxable. When it comes to 2 million records, it thows outofmemoryexception. Is there any way to handle this issue? Are there any other libraries which support converting large csv files to pdf?

Comment: Don't know what "lakh records" are, but most OOM problems can be fixed by setting -Xmx1g in the java call. Also check for memory leaks, i.e. check whether everything opened is also closed. If this still doesn't work, create a test scenario and share code and data.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here. As you see it confuses people. @TilmanHausherr lakh is 100k

Comment: @JamesZ, Thanks for the suggestion. I code i used is from this link: https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/04/convert-csv-data-to-table-in-pdf.html, I only changed the input file which has got more than 2 million records

Comment: I had a quick look, also at boxable, it seems to be clean, i.e. all that is opened is also closed. Then it's really that the PDF is getting very big, PDFBox stores all in memory.

Comment: yes, the entire pdf document is held in memory untill doc.save() method is called. Is there any way to open an outputstream and write the table row by row?

Comment: No, PDFBox doesn't support that.

Comment: is there any other library which supports that?